# Split string on "$" using regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to split a string using regex on `$` symbol but the output is not what I want.

```
string = "43$hello"
list_of_splits = re.split("$",string)

Output:
['43$hello','']

Output I want:
['43','hello']
```

It's visible by the output that "$" is a special character in regex, but now by how can I do this?

Comment: [No regex is required](https://ideone.com/d2n7OB), use `"43$hello".split('$')`. Else, escape the `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the escape character `\` : `list_of_splits = re.split("\$", str)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string split method.

```
string = "43$hello"
string.split("$")
```

Output

> `['43', 'hello']`